# Firebase Cloud Messaging: what happens if the app is closed in the middle of a bunch of subscribe/unsubscribe topic operations?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

we're using Firebase Cloud Messaging to let the user subscribe to a number of different topics based on his preferences.
On the other hand, a user can also decide to unsubscribe from any topic he has previously subscribed to.

After reading the documentation, we've found the following statement regarding iOS:

> Each time the app starts, FCM makes sure that all requested topics have been subscribed. To unsubscribe, call unsubscribeFromTopic:topic, and FCM unsubscribes from the topic in the background.

However, we haven't found the same statement on the Android docs, and indeed we haven't been able to observe the same behavior on Android.

Based on our tests, it looks like on iOS all pending subscribe/unsubscribe operations are resumed as soon as the app is started again, instead on Android if the app is closed in the middle of a bunch of subscribe/unsubscribe operations, basically the queue gets deleted and the operations have to be performed again programmatically.

Is anyone of you guys familiar with this subject? What's the expected behavior of the Firebase Android SDK?

Thanks